# Finding the expectation and random variable of a story

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Question: A bus runs from point A to point B and it only stops if a passenger needs to get off. The bus started with 20 passengers and to the drivers knowledge they were equally likely to get off at any of the 15 stops.

Calculate the expected number of stops on this trip.

I can't seem to understand what distribution function to use as it is not explicitly mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y_i$ be the random variable defined by $$ Y_i =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if no passenger wants to get off at stop i} \\
1, & \text{if at least one passenger wants to get off at step i}
\end{cases}$$

Then $$P(Y_i=0)=\left(\frac {14}{15}\right)^{20}\sim .2516$$

$$P(Y_i=1)=1-\left(\frac {14}{15}\right)^{20}\sim.7484$$

It follows that $$E[Y_i]=1-\left(\frac {14}{15}\right)^{20}\sim.7484$$

But the number of stops is just $Y_1+Y_2+\dots +Y_{15}$.  Hence the expected number of stops is $$15(1-\left(\frac {14}{15}\right)^{20})\sim 11.2258$$

Comment: Does this take into account the fact that the $Y_i$ are not independent of each other?

Comment: I have checked with a simulation and this is the correct answer.

Comment: @tomi  Only interested in the expectation, so dependence doesn't matter.  It would matter if we tried to compute the variance this way (I didn't think about how to compute that).